# How to call function from child contract in parent contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I want to call function, which returns some value from child contract inside parent contract. Child contract will serve me as configuration, aka values from config contract can be reused in parent contract.

I tried to do something like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

import "./config.sol";

contract ParentContract{

    ConfigContract two;

    constructor() public{
        two = ConfigContract(msg.sender);
    }

    function getNameFromOtherContract() public view returns(string) {
        return two.getName();
    }
}
```

Config:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

contract ConfigContract{

    constructor() public{
    }

    function getName() external pure returns (string) {
        return "Amel";
    }
}
```

I use remix, I deploy ConfigContract first:
[image]

Then I deploy ParentContract:
[image]

When I then execute getNameFromOtherContract, I get error:

> call to ParentContract.getNameFromOtherContract errored: VM error:
>   revert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the problem in `ParentContract`:

```
constructor() public{
    two = ConfigContract(msg.sender);
}
```

You are assigning a `ConfigContract` with address of `msg.sender` to `two`. But, `msg.sender` isn't actually a `ConfigContract`, unless you instantiate the `ParentContract` inside the `ConfigContract`.

Here's my solution: first deploy the `ConfigContract`, then pass it's address to the constructor of `ParentContract`, which then saves it in `two`.

I updated the constructor for you in the code below

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

contract ParentContract{

    ConfigContract two;

    constructor(ConfigContract _conf) public{
        two = _conf;
    }

    function getNameFromOtherContract() public view returns(string) {
        return two.getName();
    }
}

contract ConfigContract{

    constructor() public{
    }

    function getName() external pure returns (string) {
        return "Amel";
    }
}
```

Comment: That's it thanks. Didn't understand that contract has to be connected with address. Have to go solidity from scratch on weekend ;)

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue in the first contract.

`two = ConfigContract(msg.sender);`

The address you need to put in `ConfigContract('address')` is the address at which ConfigContract was deployed. Like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

import "./config.sol";

contract ParentContract{

    address public configContractAddress;
    ConfigContract two;

    constructor() public{
        configContractAddress = 0x610...;
        two = ConfigContract(configContractAddress);
    }

    function getNameFromOtherContract() public view returns(string) {
        return two.getName();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That's it thanks. Didn't understand that contract has to be connected with address. Have to go solidity from scratch on weekend ;) Can't accept two answers though.